# What's the cause of "PGError: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command" on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a rails app on heroku that users log in to. I periodically get this exception:

> UserSessionsController#
>   (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
>   "PGError: FATAL: terminating
>   connection due to administrator
>   command\nserver closed the connection
>   unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means
>   the server terminated
>   abnormally\n\tbef...

URL

```
POST http://secure.huckberry.com/user_sessions
```

What's a likely cause of this? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Obviously an administrator has shut down/restarted the server.

Comment: It sounds more like someone ran a pg_cancel_backend(yourpidhere); or a kill on the one backend process.  If you shut down the server you'd get an error saying it was shutting down.

Comment: I have seen similar errors today.

Comment: I have the same error on communityguides.eu/feeds reported by exceptional.

Comment: I got this when I ran multiple concurrent postgres db imports from different terminal windows (I was trying to save time importing the latest data to three different psql schemas on a single database)

Comment: have this error becose of `pg_terminate_backend`. looking a way to terminate only excessive connections.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you saw this recently, this is due to a recent bit of high-priority maintenance work to enable continuous backups on shared databases -- involving a server restart. You shouldn't worry about this error, provided it does not reproduce.  I don't think that's very likely, so happy hacking!

Comment: I upgraded some packages today and got this error. I am not sure what triggered it. But, I would definitely like to know the reason, so that I can avoid this in future.

Answer (score 4):

This probably means that something sent the server process a SIGTERM signal. This could happen is if the postmaster gets a [SIGINT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/server-shutdown.html) from something. However, if you are able to reconnect that's not the case, because the postmaster would disallow new connections.

You're probably having a clash of some kind in your application. Enable [query logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and check for something unusual.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error happen to me.  My Application server had an open connection to the database.  In my SSH terminal I added an ipaddress to the ph_hba.conf file and restarted the postgreSQL server.

That is when this error showed up.  I refreshed my web page one time and the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

This error may also appear, if you run a test suite which utilizes a database connection (PSQL in this case) and the test is still running (asynchronously).
A tear down hook may terminate the connection when the test is still running and this ends up in this error message.

Comment: how to resolve these kind of issues. I am terminating the connection in my Unit Test file in the @AfterClass hook in the java.

Comment: The SqlAlchemy devs attributed this to Python's non-deterministic shutdown. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5522#issuecomment-677825957 They noted that the error is only logged, not actually raised.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by PostgreSQL receiving an unattended upgrade (`/var/log/apt/history.log` on Ubuntu) - in PostgreSQL's logs you will see

```
2023-08-18 06:29:57 UTC LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-08-18 06:29:57 UTC LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-08-18 06:29:57 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me here was simply to vaccum my bloated tables.

You can also turn autoVaccum off for your db, but i would NOT RECOMMEND this as it can have a massive negative impact on your DB performance.

```
VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE <table_name>;
```