# Problems with Postgres starter tier

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I recently moved to Postgres and am getting intermittent errors of the form:

```
PGError: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly: 
        SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), 
               d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"xxxxxx"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum

vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/
connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:505:in `exec'
```

What can I do to get around this (apart from going back to the old Postgres Addon, which is a temporary solution I suppose).

Comment: Do you have something on the server that sends sigterm to postgresql? http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2010-09/msg00428.php

Comment: Not under my control, certainly.  Don't know if heroku may be doing something.  The site gets _very_ little traffic, so heroku may "suspend" it.

Comment: @baldmark were you able to solve this? I'm getting the same error. Heroku told me to move my database on some other server.

Comment: It was over two years ago!  At my age I have problems remembering how I solved a problem yesterday!  I clearly did solve it (or it went away) but I'm afraid I can't help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally your app should be transparently coping with database errors by re-trying its work without bugging the user. If an idle DB backend is shut down from under it, it shouldn't care, it should just make a new connection and start the transaction again. I don't know how practical Rails and ActiveRecord makes that though.

See also the question [What's the cause of "PGError: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command" on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787066/whats-the-cause-of-pgerror-fatal-terminating-connection-due-to-administrator).

It seems that Heroku will kill sometimes backends and restart servers when they're doing maintenance, which might explain your issues if your use is very infrequent.